# How to make Image in kendo grid hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to make an image in kendo grid hyper link which needs to point to the fileurl.
Fileurl has a location url which will open a document located in c folder in new tab.
Here i am giving my code:

View:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVCExample.Models.Data>()
                 .Name("PreviewGrid")
                 .Columns(columns =>
                 {
                     columns.Template(e => e.FileUrl).ClientTemplate("<img src='../../Images/pdficon.png'/>").Title("").Width(10);
                     columns.Bound(e => e.PName).Title("ReportName").Width(50).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-weight:bold" });
                     //columns.Bound(e => e.FileUrl).Title("FileName").Width(200).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-weight:bold" });

                 })
                 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:800px" })
                 .Scrollable()
                 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                     .Ajax()
                     .PageSize(20)
                     .Batch(true)
                     .ServerOperation(false)
                     .Model(model =>
                      {
                          model.Field(p => p.Name).Editable(false);
                          model.Field(p => p.FileDate).Editable(false);
                      }).Read(read => read.Action("ReadData", "Home").Data("GetFilterData"))

                      )
                .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] { 25, 50, 100, 200 }))
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Enabled(false))
    )
```

Controller:

```
IList<DataDto1> p1 = this.mycodee.GetData();
            IList<DataDto> p2 = this.mycode.GetDataFiles();
            string url = EnvSettingsTools.FIRArchivePath.ToString();
             var data = from s in p1
                               where s.pId == 5//Convert.ToInt32(filterBydesk)
                               join e in p2
                               on s.PId equals e.PId
                               where e.PDate.Date == filterByDate
                               where e.PortfolioId ==1// Convert.ToInt32(filterByportfolio)
                               select new File
                               {
                                   PName = s.pName,
                                   FileUrl = url+""+ e.FileName+".pdf"
                               };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by,

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVCExample.Models.Data>()
                 .Name("PreviewGrid")
                 .Columns(columns =>
                 {
                     
                     columns.Bound(e => e.PortfolioName).Title("ReportName").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-weight:bold" });
                     columns.Template(e => e.FileUrl).ClientTemplate("<a target='_blank' href='file:///#:data.FileUrl#'><img src='/Areas/Tools/Images/iconpdf.gif'/></a>").Title("");

                 })
)
```

Thanks for support